# I'm using Tabhost with ViewFlipper inside, when i'm calling ShowNext() and changing tabs, the view get corrupted

Tags: android

Has anyone practiced such problem?
I've created a tabhost, and inside of it I have a ViewFlipper which contains 2 ListViewers
When I am calling `ShowNext()` to display the second listView, and then moving between tabs - I keep seeing the second listView on top of all the tabs..

Anyone has any idea why does it happen?

Comment: ok nevermind - found the problem.  i read the wrong ID from the xml (i read the listview instead of flipViewer).  that what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok nevermind - found the problem. i read the wrong ID from the xml (i read the listview instead of flipViewer). that what caused the problem. – spi7fire 0 secs ago edit